# Reloading code in a dockerized node.js app with docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a trivial node.js docker app.

I am able to run it successfully, however the code reloading inside the container does not work despite mounting the volume as described in the [docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-5-edit-the-compose-file-to-add-a-bind-mount).

Directory layout:

```
my-test-app
| docker-compose.yml
| Dockerfile
| index.js
| package.json
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

index.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end("hello world");
});
server.listen(5000);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I have also tried the following with same result (app runs, not able to live reload code)

- using the official node image, instead of `alpine-node`.
- putting the application code under `./app` folder inside `my-test-app` and updating the `COPY` inside `Dockerfile` and `volumes` inside `docker-compose.yml` accordingly.

Comment: You run `node index.js` and not `nodemon` or any other reloader, why should the code refresh?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have seen the phrase "live reload" used to apply to two different types of reloading:

1. killing & restarting the application when the code changes, and
2. automatically reloading HTML & assets on a client browser when the code changes.

Based on your question, I *think* you're referring to the first type, so the answer that follows addresses that.

---

The problem here is one of **context**.

Remember that the docker container is isolated from your host - specifically, the processes running in the container are distinct from (and generally cannot interact with) processes running on the host. In your case, you have chosen to mount a host directory in the container, but that's just the filesystem, not the processes.

Think through what your Docker image does when you instantiate a new container: it runs `node index.js` in the `WORKDIR`. Where is the code to stop it and restart it when the code changes? Presumably it's running in a process on the **host**. This means that it cannot touch the node process running in the **container** (because it's isolated).

Now, you haven't mentioned what method you're using to handle the live reloading, but that shouldn't make too much of a difference. They all basically work the same way: on a change to the application code, kill the existing process and start a new one.

To solve this, you have two options:

1. run the "live reloading" code inside the container, or
2. run your development code outside the container

For the first, you could follow @MarkS's suggestion and use [`nodemon`](https://github.com/remy/nodemon). This should be as simple as replacing

```
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

in your Dockerfile with

```
CMD ["nodemon", "index.js"]
```

provided, of course, that you have `nodemon` properly installed in the image.

The alternative, and this is what I do, is to run the code on the host outside the Docker environment during development, and then package it up in an image at deployment. This solves two problems:

1. the problem you're running into with isolated node processes, and
2. permission problems.

Remember that apps running in Docker are run as `root`. This means that if your app creates files, they're going to be owned by `root`. I tried developing in a Docker environment, but got frustrated by problems where, for example, I wanted to delete a file created by the app and had to `sudo` (sign in as `root`) just to clean up stuff.

Comment: You should not run as root https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between what I have and what you have is that I don't have the COPY directive in my Dockerfile. Try removing that and see if it works.

I also use nodemon to automatically restart the node server when the code changes:

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem even though I was using nodemon. The solution that worked for me was to change the volume of the node app inside the docker compose file to read from `/src` or wherever your app files are in.