# How can I make my docker container update on changes to my source files?

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm building a Django/React app using docker-compose, and I'd like it to reload my apps when a change is made, so far I've tried adding  `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING`,
adding npm-watch to my package.json, but it doesn't seem to be able to detect changes in the host file.

Ideally I don't want to have to run `docker-compose up --build` every time I make a change since it's making development tedious.

edit: I should mention that the apps both reload running outside of docker (npm start (cra default) and python manage.py runserver) as expected.

Changes are detected inside the container, but the react app will not rebuild.

I'm using Windows 10 also.

Is there something wrong with my files or something else I should be doing here?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/core
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build: ./frontend
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - './frontend:/app/'
      - '/frontend/node_modules'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    depends_on:
      - backend
    # Enable interactive terminal (crucial for react container to work)
    stdin_open: true 
    tty: true
```

backend Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3 
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code/
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

frontend Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app/

COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: What is the `npm start` command? Are you reloading your server on code changes?
By mounting the directory with your code as a volume it should sync with the container.

Comment: npm start is the default from create-react-app (react-scripts start)

Comment: I don't know how to get it to reload, that's a big part of my problem. I've tried searching but no luck

Comment: I should mention that the apps both reload running outside of docker (npm start (cra default) and python manage.py runserver) as expected, just not inside containers

Comment: Either of  these any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223173/reloading-code-in-a-dockerized-node-js-app-with-docker-compose or https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-enable-live-reload-on-docker-based-applications/

Comment: do you want to reload the container when you change the code inside the container or outside(host)???.

Comment: @JohnXF no neither of those helped

Comment: I want to reload from host changes, it doen't seem good practice to edit the container code @S.Sachith

Comment: you can use nodemon --watch with exec to run a command when something change I think with react but I don't know if nodemon working with django @Danielle

Answer (score 2):

Instead of copying you should mount volumes directly to the folder where you run the code on your docker image. In that way your code changes will be reflected in your app.

Example in docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
      - "local_source_destination:/server_source_destination"
```

In your frontend docker-compose-yml you have:

```
    volumes:
  - '.:/frontend/app'
```

but in your Dockerfile your have

```
COPY . /app/
```

So it seems like your are mixing up where to mount your volume. Make sure '.' is where your root of your code folder is or change it accordingly.

Try something like:

```
 volumes:
  - '.:/app'
```

As that seems to be the location your server wants your code to be.

If your code is correctly mounted to the right destination it might be that you are not running your watch script from inside the docker container. Try running:

```
docker exec -itw source_destination_in_container your_container_name command_to_run_watch
```

Comment: I've actually tried changing the volumes to that, and it wont even run like that without the COPY lines

Comment: What is it that won't run? docker or the application?

Comment: I have changed that, but it still doesn't fix the issue of me having to rebuild on every change

Comment: Try changing something in your code and then see if that change is reflected in your container. If it is changed on your docker container I would suspect that you are not running what should listen to changes on your docker container but on your local machine.

Comment: That is part of the problem, docker-compose is running the same start commands I run outside of the container, the ones outside of a container do detect changes, but I can't get those to transfer to a container whilst docker is running

Comment: If you manage to mount your code onto the container with a volume and make sure it is mounted in the right place it should be reflecting your changes onto the docker image. If you use the COPY command in a docker image it will just copy the code over at build time and not reflect your changes.

Comment: It does reflect the changes if I look inside the code on the container, but it doesn't reflect that in the browser. I'm using the base create-react-app and changing the text but it doesn't change unless I rebuild the image. I don't really understand how to get around using COPY commands since the image will not run without them

Comment: So you want hot reloading? Or just a watch to build on changes? Here you have a good explanation of using volumes instead of copy: https://olshansky.medium.com/hot-reloading-with-local-docker-development-1ec5dbaa4a65

Comment: Yes, hot reload is what I want. I tried making the changes in the volume but it doesn't seem to make a difference. The code change is reflected in the  container but not in the browser/build

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643045/running-development-server-with-create-react-app-inside-of-a-docker-container this is somewhat similar to your problem.